# Maven - Using Sigar with Java

Tags: java, maven, sigar

I am trying to use Sigar in my Java Maven application, i added the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource</groupId>
        <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

but it was throwing thr following exception:

```
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: no libsigar-amd64-linux.so in java.library.path
at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.loadLibrary(Sigar.java:172)
at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.<clinit>(Sigar.java:100)
at com.ro.terminal.model.utils.TerminalUtils.<clinit>(TerminalUtils.java:28)
at com.ro.terminal.model.service.SyncModule.init(SyncModule.java:187)
at com.ro.terminal.main.Terminalinitializer.<init>(Terminalinitializer.java:124)
at com.ro.terminal.main.Terminalinitializer$3.call(Terminalinitializer.java:339)
at com.ro.terminal.main.Terminalinitializer$3.call(Terminalinitializer.java:1)
at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

after googling i knew that i have to add the needed `.ddl` and `.so` files in the application and add the path to `java.library.path`,

i downloaded the files from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sigar/files/sigar/1.6/) and added them under resources/sigar-lib and tried adding the following to my `pom.xml`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <org.hyperic.sigar.path>${sigar.libs}</org.hyperic.sigar.path>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

       ___________________________

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>

            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <java.library.path>${sigar.libs}</java.library.path>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

     ______________________

     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${sigar.libs}:${java.library.path}</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

the `${sigar.libs}` is defined as follows:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <sigar.libs>${basedir}/src/main/resources/sigar-lib</sigar.libs>

    <build.timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</build.timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd-HHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>

</properties>
```

what am i doing wrong? i am running eclipse oxygen on Ubuntu 17.10

project screenshot:

[image]